# Opening Gmail in a browser and logging into it automatically

Tags: google-chrome, powershell

I want to open gmail automatially and login to it using the credentials.

For this, I have written a .ps1 script which contains the following code :

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
call WshShell.Run("https://www.gmail.com", 1, false) 

WScript.Sleep 2000
WshShell.SendKeys "prudhvi"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "prudhvi9"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Quit()
```

This throws the following error :

```
At C:\Users\admin\Desktop\sample.ps1:2 char:46
+ call WshShell.Run("https://www.gmail.com", 1, false)
+                                              ~
Missing expression after ','.
At C:\Users\admin\Desktop\sample.ps1:2 char:47
+ call WshShell.Run("https://www.gmail.com", 1, false)
+                                               ~~~~~
Unexpected token 'false' in expression or statement.
At C:\Users\admin\Desktop\sample.ps1:2 char:46
+ call WshShell.Run("https://www.gmail.com", 1, false)
+                                              ~
Missing closing ')' in expression.
At C:\Users\admin\Desktop\sample.ps1:2 char:52
+ call WshShell.Run("https://www.gmail.com", 1, false)
+                                                    ~ 
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
At C:\Users\admin\Desktop\sample.ps1:13 char:14
+ WScript.Quit()
+              ~
An expression was expected after '('.
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterToken
```

What might the error be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is confusion between Powershell (.ps1) and VBScript (.vbs). The code in sample is VBScript, and as such must be run with `cscript c:\path\to\script.vbs` (text mode) or `wscript c:\path\to\script.vbs` (GUI mode) scripting host.

Comment: prudhvi9 is NOT your password I hope ;-)